# How to move VPS to another hosting provider?

Tags: vps

I was looking for a way to move one VPS server(all OS configs, application structure etc) to another VPS hosting provider. I mean completely. Without manual reconfiguration and reinstalling all the applications after moving.

Is it possible?

I noticed that even if my hosting provider offers server images - it's not possible to install them on any other VPS hosting provider.

P.S. Let's assume that we're moving between equal OS versions.

Comment: This is pretty much a duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/153100/ there's not much (if any) difference between different VPS providers and different managed server providers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have access to the server image itself, and the provider you're moving **to** is using the exact same virtualization technology as the one you're moving **from**, and the provider you're moving to will allow you to boot a server image directly (rather than going through the normal provisioning process), then it could be as simple a matter as copying the OS image and changing the IPs.

That isn't likely to be the case, however, given the way most VPS providers work. Instead, you're probably better off doing the migration the old-fashioned way.